# What is the meaning of Shri Krishan Govind Hare Murari by Jagjit singh?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, translation-request, tradition, shloka

[Source Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PontsHDC43A)

[Lyrics](https://www.smule.com/song/jagjit-singh-shri-krishna-govind-hare-murari-karaoke-lyrics/7329761_7329761/arrangement)

This  is a bhajan by [Jagjit Singh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagjit_Singh) Ji. It's difficult for me to understand the meaning of the lyrics in this song.

What is the exact meaning of these verses?

> ''**Shri Krishna Govinda Hare Murari
> He Nath Narayan Vasudeva**''
>
> **achu.tam kesh.vam naam nara.yanam krishna damo.daram vasu.devam hari**
>
> **kukam karoti vaaa.aachalam
> panguu.lan ghe.the giram
> yat kripa tam hum,
> bande parma.nand madhvam**

Comment: As far as I know.... The first 2 lines are the different names of Shri Krishna..

Comment: Regarding the 3rd line, here is the meaning https://greenmesg.org/stotras/krishna/mukam_karoti_vacalam.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr - the first two verses are the names of Lord Krishna, the last one extols his virtues and salutes him.

---

Here's a line-by-line breakdown:

> Sri Krishna Govinda Hare Murari |
> He Nath Narayan Vasudeva ||

These are simply names and titles of Lord Krishna:

- *Sri Krishna* is the name of Vishnu's 8th avatar
- *Govinda* was how Krishna was referred to when he was young
- *Hare* is used when addressing Lord Vishnu, and by extension, Krishna
- *He Nath* is equivalent to 'O lord'
- *Narayana* is another name for Vishnu
- *Vasudeva* means 'son of Vasudeva,' who was Krishna's father

The next line is also titles:

> achyutam keshavam ram narayanam |
> krishna damodaram vasudevam hari ||

- *achyutam* means permanent, imperishable, eternal, etc. ([source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=achyutam&dir=au))
- *keshav* is a name for Krishna, the -am ending is a grammatical thing ([source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=kezava&dir=se))
- what sounds like 'naam' in the song is actually supposed to be 'ram'
- *narayan*, like said before, is Vishnu
- *krishna*, of course, is Krishna
- *damodaram* is a name of Krishna ([source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=damodaram&dir=au))
- *vasudevam* is a way of referring to the 'son of Vasudeva'
- *hari* is Vishnu

> Kuukam Karoti Vaacaalam, Panggum Langghayate Girim |
> Yat-Kripaa Tamaham Vande, Param ananda Maadhavam ||

This verse is more than names:

- *kuukam* means 'mute', although some versions write this as *muukam*, which has the same meaning. *karodi* comes from 'kar' (do/make), and it means something along the lines of 'one who makes it so that...'. *vachalam* means 'talkative,' or 'able to speak.' ([source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=kukam&dir=au), [source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=vacalam&dir=au)). So, 'He who allows the mute to talk.'
- pangu means 'lame,' or 'crippled.' *langghayate* means 'cross,' or 'traverse.' *girim* comes from 'giri,' which means mountains. ([source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=lame&dir=au), [source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=laGghanaM&dir=se), [source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=giri&dir=au) ) So, 'He who allows the lame to cross mountains'
- *yat-kripa* means 'that holiness,' or 'that grace'. 'Tamaham' is a grammatical feature, but it means 'I [verb] him.' The verb here is *vande*, which means 'praise' ([source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=yat&dir=au), [source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=kripa&dir=au), [source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=tamaham&dir=au)). So, 'That Grace, that Holiness, I praise him.'
- *parama*, here, means 'absolute. 'ananda' means 'happiness.' *maadhavam* is again a way to refer to Krishna ([source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=parama&dir=au), [source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=ananda&dir=au)). So, 'Absolute happiness that comes from Krishna.'

Put together, the final verse says:

> O, he who can endow the mute with speech, he who can let even the crippled cross over mountains...
> that Grace, I praise him, for with him, Madhava, there is the absolute pleasure.